# How can i increase a section size to fit in a form, a gallery or a big element?

Tags: javascript, html, css, forms, bootstrap-4

So, im at almost the final stage of development of my classroom web but i need some fixes. Thank you all for all the knowledge you have shared with me these days by the way. So im using a gsap js function to create an effect of superposition between sections in my page, and everything works fine when im writing or adding things with a reasonable size, but when i have tried adding a gallery or a form, in this case, i cant seem to find the way to increase the size of the section or whatever to make it fit. I have tried using the height property, padding, margin, line-height, but nothing seems to work. Can you help me fix this problem please? Thank you all! Snippet below:

```js
const form = document.getElementById('form');
const username = document.getElementById('username');
const email = document.getElementById('email');
const direccion = document.getElementById('direccion');
const telefono = document.getElementById('telefono');

form.addEventListener('submit', e => {
    e.preventDefault();

    checkInputs();
});

function checkInputs() {
    var usernameValue = username.value.trim();
    var emailValue = email.value.trim();
    var direccionValue = direccion.value.trim();
    var telefonoValue = telefono.value.trim();

    if(usernameValue === '') {
        setErrorFor(username, 'Introduzca un nombre, por favor');
    } else {
        setSuccessFor(username);
    }

    if(emailValue === '') {
        setErrorFor(email, 'Introduzca un email, por favor');
    } else if (!isEmail(emailValue)) {
        setErrorFor(email, 'El email introducido no es valido, intentelo de nuevo');
    } else {
        setSuccessFor(email);
    }

    if(direccionValue === '') {
        setErrorFor(direccion, 'Introduzca una direccion, por favor');
    } else {
        setSuccessFor(direccion);
    }

    if(telefonoValue === '') {
        setErrorFor(telefono, 'Introduzca un telefono, por favor');
    } else if(telefono.value.length !== 9) {
        setErrorFor(telefono, 'Su numero no tiene la longitud adecuada');
    } else{
        setSuccessFor(telefono);
    }
}

function setErrorFor(input, message) {
    const formControl = input.parentElement;
    const small = formControl.querySelector('small');
    formControl.className = 'form-control error';
    small.innerText = message;
}

function setSuccessFor(input) {
    const formControl = input.parentElement;
    formControl.className = 'form-control success';
}

function isEmail(email) {
    return /^(([^<>()\[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+(\.[^<>()\[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+)*)|(".+"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$/.test(email);
}
gsap.registerPlugin(ScrollTrigger);

gsap.utils.toArray('.segmento').forEach(section => {
  ScrollTrigger.create({
    trigger: section,
    start: 'top top',
    pin: true,
    pinSpacing: false
  });
});
```

```css
html {
    scroll-behavior: smooth;
}

.navbar-nav>li {
    padding-left: 20px;
    padding-right: 20px;
}

nav {
    background-color: #000033;
    opacity: 0.95;
}

.cookie-container {
    position: fixed;
    bottom: -100%;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    background: #2f3640;
    color: #f5f6fa;
    padding: 15px 32px;
    box-shadow: 0 -2px 16px rgba(47, 54, 64, 0.151);
    transition: 400ms;
}

.cookie-container a {
    color: #f5f6fa;
}

.cookie-container.active {
    bottom: 0;
}

.cookie-btn {
    background: #e84118;
    border: 0;
    color: #f5f6fa;
    padding: 12px 48px;
    font-size: 18px;
    margin-bottom: 16px;
    border-radius: 8px;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.column-right {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    padding: 2rem;
}

.column-left {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: flex-start;
    color: #000;
    padding: 0rem 2rem;
}

.column-left h1 {
    margin-bottom: 3rem;
    font-size: 2rem;
    font-style: italic;
}

.column-left p {
    margin-bottom: 2rem;
    font-size: 2rem;
    line-height: 1.1;
}
.column-normal{

  vertical-align: middle;
  text-align: center;
  font-size:3rem;
}
.column-normal p{
  margin-bottom: 2rem;
  font-size: 4rem;
  line-height: 4;
}
.column-normal .image{
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  max-width: 750px;
  max-height:400px;
}
.container{
  margin:0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.segmento {
    background: #EC96D3;
}
.cuatro {
  background: #66488f;
}

section{
  margin:0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
  height: 100vh;
  position:static;
  display:flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;

}
body{
  overflow-x: hidden;
}
section .container{
  display:grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
  height:95vh;
  padding: 3rem calc((100vw - 1300px)/2);
}
section .containersp{
  display: block;
  padding: 3rem calc((100vw - 1300px)/2);
  height:50vh;
}
section .containerfrm{
  display: block;
  padding: 3rem calc((100vw - 1300px)/2);
  height:800vh;
  background-color: #fff;
    border-radius: 5px;
    box-shadow: 0 2px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 400px;
    max-width: 100%;
}
section .containerGAL{
  padding: 3rem calc((100vw - 1300px)/2);

}
.gallery-container{
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
  grid-template-rows: repeat(3, 300px);
  width: 80%;
  margin: 100px auto;

}
.gallery-container .gallery-card{
  overflow: hidden;
}
.gallery-container .gallery-card a > img{
  width:100%;
  height: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
  transition: 0.5s;
}
.gallery-container .gallery-card a{
  width:100%;
  height: 100%;
}
.gallery-container .gallery-card a > img:hover{
  transform: scale(1.5);
}
section .containerimg{
  display: block;
  padding: 3rem calc((100vw - 1300px)/2);
  height:60vh;
}
section .text {
  color:#fff;
}
section .image{
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  max-width: 750px;
  max-height:400px;
}

footer {
    margin: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    position: sticky;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    display: flex;
    color: #fff;
    background: #000033;
    padding: 50px;
    font-size: 14px;
    flex-flow: row wrap;

}

.footer-left img {
    width: 50%;
    max-width: 150px;
    max-height: 60px;
    margin-top: 20px;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.socials {
    text-align: center;
}

.footer>* {
    flex: 1 100%;
}

.footer-left {
    margin-right: 1.25em;
    margin-bottom: 2em;
}

.footer-right {
    display: flex;
    flex-flow: row wrap;
}

.footer-right>* {
    flex: 1 50%;
    margin-right: 1.25em;
}

.box a {
    color: #999;
}

.footer-bottom {
    text-align: center;
    color: #999;
    padding-top: 50px;
}

.footer-left p {
    padding-right: 20%;
    color: #999;
}

.socials a {
    background: #364a62;
    width: 40px;
    height: 40px;
    display: inline-block;
    margin-right: 10px;
    padding: 10px;
}

@media screen and (min-width: 600px) {
    .footer-right>* {
        flex: 1;
    }
    .footer-left {
        flex: 1 0px;
    }
    .footer-right {
        flex: 2 0px;
    }
}

@media (max-width: 600px) {
    .footer {
        padding: 15px;
    }
}

.btninicio {
    position: fixed;
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    background: #6F1E51;
    bottom: 40px;
    right: 50px;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 50px;
    color: white;
    font-size: 22px;
}

.footer h2 {
    font-weight: 600;
    font-size: 17px;
}

.footer ul {
    list-style: none;
    padding-left: 0;
}

.footer li {
    line-height: 2em;
}

.footer a {
    text-decoration: none;
}
button{
  cursor: pointer;
}
.form {
    padding: 30px 40px;
}

.form-control {
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    padding-bottom: 20px;
    position: relative;
}

.form-control label {
    display: inline-block;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
}

.form-control input {
    border: 2px solid #f0f0f0;
    border-radius: 4px;
    display: block;
    font-family: inherit;
    font-size: 14px;
    padding: 10px;
    width: 100%;
}

.form-control input:focus {
    outline: 0;
    border-color: #777;
}

.form-control.success input {
    border-color: #2ecc71;
}

.form-control.error input {
    border-color: #e74c3c;
}

.form-control i {
    visibility: hidden;
    position: absolute;
    top: 40px;
    right: 10px;
}

.form-control.success i.fa-check-circle {
    color: #2ecc71;
    visibility: visible;
}

.form-control.error i.fa-exclamation-circle {
    color: #e74c3c;
    visibility: visible;
}

.form-control small {
    color: #e74c3c;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    visibility: hidden;
}

.form-control.error small {
    visibility: visible;
}

.form button {
    background-color: #051261;
    border: 2px solid #051261;
    border-radius: 4px;
    color: #fff;
    display: block;
    font-family: inherit;
    font-size: 16px;
    padding: 10px;
    margin-top: 20px;
    width: 100%;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 480px) {

    .social-panel-container.visible {
        transform: translateX(0px);
    }

    .floating-btn {
        right: 10px;
    }
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="es">

<head>

    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/animate.css/4.1.1/animate.min.css"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Oswald&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.4/css/all.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="contact.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="lightbox.min.css">
    <title>Contacto</title>
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="log.png" />
    <style>
    section .containerfrm{
      display: block;
      padding: 3rem calc((100vw - 1300px)/2);

      background-color: #fff;
        border-radius: 5px;
        box-shadow: 0 2px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
        overflow: hidden;
        width: 1000px;
        max-width: 100%;
    }
    .form {
        padding: 30px 40px;
    }

    .form input{
      font-size: 10px;
    }

    .form-control {
        margin-bottom: 10px;
        padding-bottom: 20px;
        position: relative;
    }

    .form-control label {
        display: inline-block;
        margin-bottom: 5px;
    }

    .form-control input {
        border: 2px solid #f0f0f0;
        border-radius: 4px;
        display: block;
        font-family: inherit;
        font-size: 14px;
        padding: 10px;
        width: 100%;
    }

    .form-control input:focus {
        outline: 0;
        border-color: #777;
    }

    .form-control.success input {
        border-color: #2ecc71;
    }

    .form-control.error input {
        border-color: #e74c3c;
    }

    .form-control i {
        visibility: hidden;
        position: absolute;
        top: 40px;
        right: 10px;
    }

    .form-control.success i.fa-check-circle {
        color: #2ecc71;
        visibility: visible;
    }

    .form-control.error i.fa-exclamation-circle {
        color: #e74c3c;
        visibility: visible;
    }

    .form-control small {
        color: #e74c3c;
        position: absolute;
        bottom: 0;
        left: 0;
        visibility: hidden;
    }

    .form-control.error small {
        visibility: visible;
    }

    .form button {
        background-color: #051261;
        border: 2px solid #051261;
        border-radius: 4px;
        color: #fff;
        display: block;
      cursor: pointer;
        font-family: inherit;
        font-size: 16px;
        padding: 10px;
        margin-top: 20px;
        width: 100%;
    }

    @media screen and (max-width: 480px) {

        .social-panel-container.visible {
            transform: translateX(0px);
        }

        .floating-btn {
            right: 10px;
        }
    }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark  sticky-top">
        <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNavDropdown" aria-controls="navbarNavDropdown" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">SneakerReport</a>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNavDropdown">
            <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto mt-2 mt-lg-0">
                <li class="nav-item active">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="ini.html"> <i class="fa fa-home"></i> Inicio <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="histo.html"> <i class="fa fa-book"></i> Historia</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#"><i class="fa fa-user"></i> Contacto</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                    <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdownMenuLink" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false"><i class="fa fa-certificate"></i>
                        Marcas
                    </a>
                    <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdownMenuLink">
                        <a class="dropdown-item" href="sup.html">Supreme <i class="fa fa-exclamation"></i></a>
                        <a class="dropdown-item" href="pal.html">Palace <i class="fa fa-exclamation"></i></a>
                    </div>
                </li>
            </ul>
            <form class="form-inline my-2 my-lg-0">
                <input class="form-control mr-sm-2" type="search" placeholder="Search" aria-label="Search">
                <button class="btn btn-outline-success my-2 my-sm-0" type="submit">Search</button>
            </form>
        </div>
    </nav>
    <section class="segmento">
      <div class = "containersp">
        <div class="column-normal">
            <p class="text animate__animated animate__heartBeat animate_slow animate__infinite">¿Necesitas mas información?</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </section>

    <section class="segmento dos">
      <div class = "container">
        <div class="column-right">
          <img src="me.jpg" alt="Levv" class="image" />
        </div>
        <div class="column-left">
          <h1 class="text">
            Bienvenido
          </h1>
            <p class="text">¡Buenas! Soy Gonzalo Canteli y un dia como hoy en septiembre del 2018 empecé ademas de mis estudios informáticos, a interesarme por la moda
              y la cultura alrededor de ella. Este proyecto es una demostración de algo grande que quiero llevar a cabo.¡Espero que te guste!

            </p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </section>
    <section class="segmento dos">
      <div class = "container">
        <div class="column-left">
            <p class="text">Si lo desea, puede comunicarse con nosotros a traves de nuestro <a href="#" style="color:pink"onclick="JavaScript:window.location='mailto:'+'gon73li'+'@'+'gmail'+'.com'" > email</a>

            </p>
        </div>
        <div class="column-right">
          <p><iframe src="https://www.google.com/maps/embed?pb=!1m18!1m12!1m3!1d3040.6082074751016!2d-3.678305028399778!3d40.35103652134233!2m3!1f0!2f0!3f0!3m2!1i1024!2i768!4f13.1!3m3!1m2!1s0xd4226bdd9ea0d85%3A0xafc17f8fcff53d6!2sCentro%20Cultural%20los%20Rosales!5e0!3m2!1ses!2ses!4v1609434348458!5m2!1ses!2ses" width="400" height="300" frameborder="0" style="border:0;" allowfullscreen="" aria-hidden="false" tabindex="0"></iframe></p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </section>
    <section class="segmento">
      <div class = "containerfrm">
        <div class="column-normal">
          <form id="form" class="form">
                <div class="form-control">
                    <label for="username">Nombre y Apellidos</label>
                    <input type="text" placeholder="P ej: Juan Perez" id="username" />
                    <i class="fas fa-check-circle"></i>
                    <i class="fas fa-exclamation-circle"></i>
                    <small>Error</small>
                </div>
                <div class="form-control">
                    <label for="username">Email</label>
                    <input type="email" placeholder="juan@perez.com" id="email" />
                    <i class="fas fa-check-circle"></i>
                    <i class="fas fa-exclamation-circle"></i>
                    <small>Error</small>
                </div>
                <div class="form-control">
                    <label for="username">Direccion</label>
                    <input type="text" placeholder="Avenida de Andalucia 4" id="direccion"/>
                    <i class="fas fa-check-circle"></i>
                    <i class="fas fa-exclamation-circle"></i>
                    <small>Error</small>
                </div>
                <div class="form-control">
                    <label for="username">Telefono</label>
                    <input type="tel" placeholder="643936483" id="telefono"/>
                    <i class="fas fa-check-circle"></i>
                    <i class="fas fa-exclamation-circle"></i>
                    <small>Error</small>
                </div>
            <input name="aceptacion" type="checkbox"/>
            Acepto el uso de mi informacion con fines informativos
            <br />

                <button style="cursor:pointer">Enviar</button>
            <button id="boton" style="cursor:pointer">Reiniciar</button>
            </form>


        </div>
      </div>
    </section>
    <footer class="footer segmento cuatro" style="bottom:0">
        <div class="footer-left">
            <img src="yzy.png" alt="snk">
            <p>SneakerReport nace como una solucion para que gente de todas las edades tenga una posibilidad
                de acceder a moda limitada sin pagar reventa.</p>
            <div class="socials">
                <a href="https://www.facebook.com/profile.php?id=100011277759449" target="_blank"><i class=" fab fa-facebook"></i> </a>
                <a href="https://twitter.com/Gonzaacdz" target="_blank"><i class=" fab fa-twitter"></i> </a>
                <a href="https://www.instagram.com/gx.neee/?hl=es" target="_blank"><i class=" fab fa-instagram"></i> </a>
            </div>
        </div>
        <ul class="footer-right">
            <li>
                <h2>Paginas en las que tenemos soporte</h2>
                <ul class="box">
                    <li><a href="sup.html"> Supreme </a></li>
                    <li><a href="#"> Palace </a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li>
                <h2>Otras secciones</h2>
                <ul class="box">
                    <li><a href="histo.html"> Historia </a></li>
                    <li><a href="#"> Inscribete </a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li>
                <h2>Direccion</h2>
                <ul class="box">
                    <li>  </li>
                    <li>  </li>
                    <li> Madrid, ES, 28021 </li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
        <div class="footer-bottom">
            <p>Todos los derechos reservados a &copy;Gonzalo Canteli 2020 </p>
        </div>
    </footer>
    <a class="btninicio" href="#"> <i class=" fas fa-angle-double-up"></i> </a>
    <div class="cookie-container">
        <p>Utilizamos cookies propias y de terceros para mejorar la experiencia del usuario a través de su navegación. Si continúas navegando aceptas su uso. <a href="#">Política de cookies. </a></p>
        <button class="cookie-btn">
            De acuerdo
        </button>
    </div>

    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/gsap/3.5.1/gsap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/gsap/3.5.1/ScrollTrigger.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/aos@next/dist/aos.js"></script>
    <script>
        AOS.init();
    </script>

    <script src="cookieplugin.js"></script>
    <script src="lightbox-plus-jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="lightbox.min.js"></script>
    <script type ="text/javascript" src="contact.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    document.getElementById("boton").onclick=clear;
    function clear(){
      var i;
        for (i = 0; (i < document.forms.length); i++) {
          document.forms[i].reset();
        }
    }
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: hi. why do you need `height: 800vh` in `section`?

Comment: I was trying to fix it and that was one of the ideas i got, but no real effect

Comment: Do you just want to remove this rule `height: 800vh`?

Comment: No no, i just want the section to br big enough to show the form real size, because if you check the snippet, the footer covers the last part of it. The vh edit was a solution i came up with but didnt work out